# List of coordinates into list of slices

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to convert a list of tuples representing (x, y) coordinates like this :

```py
[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
```

into a list of equivalent slices like this :

```
[(slice_a_x, slice_a_y), (slice_b_x, slice_b_y), ...]?
```

For example :

```py
[(22, 9), (22, 10), (22, 11), (22, 12),
 (23, 9), (23, 10), (23, 11), (23, 12),
 (24, 9), (24, 10), (24, 11), (24, 12)]   

# would be [(slice(22, 25), slice(9, 13)), ]
```

```py
[(22, 8), (22, 26), (23, 8), (23, 26), (24, 8), (24, 26)]  

# would be [(slice(22, 25), slice(8, 9)), (slice(22, 25), slice(26, 27)), ]
```

```py
[(22, 8), (22, 26)]  

# would be [(slice(22, 23), slice(8, 9)), (slice(22, 23), slice(26, 27)), ]
```

**EDIT :**

Based on the proposal of Jupri, another version that takes care of particular cases (gaps, holes,...) :

```py
import numpy as np
import more_itertools as mit

coordinates = np.array(coordinates)

# List of coordinates with y as interval
y_consec = [list(g) for g in mit.consecutive_groups(coordinates[:, 1])]
y_consec = [(min(g), max(g)) for g in y_consec for _ in range(len(g))]
y_coords = np.array(sorted(list(set(zip(*[y_consec, *coordinates[:, :-1].T])))), dtype=object)

# List of configurations following y
y_confs = sorted(list(set(c for c in y_coords[:, 0])))

# Split coordinates into homogeneous groups of y
y_groups = [[x for y, x in y_coords if y == c] for c in y_confs]

# Search consecutives x for each group
xyz = []
for y_conf, y_group in zip(y_confs, y_groups):
    x_consec = [(min(g), max(g)) for g in [list(group) for group in _mit.consecutive_groups(y_group)]]
    xyz.extend([(x, y_conf) for x in x_consec])

# Results
for s in xyz:
    print(s)
```

Comment: What is your logic to make these `(22, 8)` eg.?

Comment: @DanielHao This is what it looks like: The coordinates are points in a grid, and the slices are the top-left and bottom-right corners of rectangles that are filled in completely.

Comment: maybe first find `"any working way"`

Comment: maybe you could use `zip(*list)` (with `*`) to convert to lists `(22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24)` and `(9, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 12)` and later get `min()` `max()` from every list and later create `slice(min(...), max(...)+1)`. But all problem is if there are gaps in number - it may need to run some complex code with `for`-loop. So maybe first find `any working code` before you will search `the most efficient code`

Comment: why do you use slice ?

Comment: Just to make the question clear. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
coordinates = [(22, 9), (22, 10), (22, 11), (22, 12),
 (23, 9), (23, 10), (23, 11), (23, 12),
 (24, 9), (24, 10), (24, 11), (24, 12)]
```

*You can use **more_itertools.consecutive_groups** :*

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

# all x,y values unique and sorted

x = sorted(set([c[0] for c in coordinates]))
y = sorted(set([c[1] for c in coordinates]))

# consecutive groups, find max and min

gx = [[min(g),max(g)+1] for g in [list(group) for group in consecutive_groups(x)]]
gy = [[min(g),max(g)+1] for g in [list(group) for group in consecutive_groups(y)]]

# combine every min_x, max_x, with every min_y, max_y

results = [(mx[slice(2)], my[slice(2)]) for mx in gx for my in gy ]

print( results )
```

Comment: Nice solution.
I didn't know more_itertools!